# Question about the measure extension on ring

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I get confused about the measure extension on a ring $R$. Suppose the whole space is $X$. The logic goes as we first define measure on $R$, then we build some set $H(R)=\{A\subset X;\exists \{A_n\}_{n\in N^+} \subset R,s.t. A \subset \cup_{n \in N^+}A_n\}$. Then we show $H(R)$ is a $\sigma$ ring and we can introduce an outer measure $\mu^*$ based on $\mu$. $\forall F \in H(R),\mu^*(F)=inf\{\sum_{1}^{\infty}\mu(A_i);A_i \in R, F\subset \cup_{i \in N^+}A_i\}$.

My question is about the outer measure we define

> I think $\mu^*(F) = inf\{\mu(\cup_{i\in N^+} A_i);A_i \in R, F\subset \cup_{i \in N^+}A_i\}$. However, since ring $R$ is not closed by countable union, $\mu(\cup_{i\in N^+} A_i)$ does not exist if $\cup_{i\in N^+} A_i \notin R$. Should I define $\mu^*$ as $\mu^*(F) = inf\{\mu(\cup_{i\in N^+} A_i);A_i \in R, F\subset \cup_{i \in N^+}A_i \in R\}$(2)? But this definition is different from the one above.

Checking (2) satisfies the countably subadditive is hard, but it does satisfy other requirements to be an outer measure.

Comment: Why should the $A_i$ be disjoint? (Also be careful of "$\in$" versus "$\subset$")

Comment: Sorry about the typo. I have already updated the question.

Comment: If you define $\mu^*$ as (2), $\mu^*$ may not be sub-additive. Here is a example: let $X = \Bbb N$, and $R$ be the ring of **finite** subsets of $\Bbb N$. For each $A \in R$, define $$\mu(A)= \sum_{n \in A} \frac{1}{2^n}$$ Using the definition (2) above, we have $$\mu^*(\Bbb N) = inf\{\mu(\cup_{i\in N^+} A_i);A_i \in R, \Bbb N\subset \cup_{i \in N^+}A_i \in R\}= inf \: \emptyset= +\infty$$ So we have, $\Bbb N = \bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N} \{n\}$ and $$\mu^*(\Bbb N) =  +\infty > 2 = \sum_{n \in \Bbb N}  \frac{1}{2^n} =  \sum_{n \in \Bbb N} \mu^*(\{n\})$$

Comment: Why $\mu^*(N)=inf \emptyset= \infty$